# Restructure output of R summary function

Tags: r, summary

Is there an easy way to change the output format for R's summary function so that the results print in a column instead of row?  R does this automatically when you pass summary a data frame. I'd like to print summary statistics in a column when I pass it a single vector.  So instead of this:

```
>summary(vector)

Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
1.000   1.000   2.000   6.699   6.000 559.000
```

It would look something like this:

```
  >summary(vector)

    Min.    1.000
    1st Qu. 1.000 
    Median  2.000  
    Mean    6.699
    3rd Qu. 6.000   
    Max.    559.000
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure. Treat it as a `data.frame`:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- sample(30, 100, TRUE)

summary(x)
#    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#    1.00   10.00   15.00   16.03   23.25   30.00 
summary(data.frame(x))
#        x        
#  Min.   : 1.00  
#  1st Qu.:10.00  
#  Median :15.00  
#  Mean   :16.03  
#  3rd Qu.:23.25  
#  Max.   :30.00
```

For slightly more usable output, you can use `data.frame(unclass(.))`:

```
data.frame(val = unclass(summary(x)))
#           val
# Min.     1.00
# 1st Qu. 10.00
# Median  15.00
# Mean    16.03
# 3rd Qu. 23.25
# Max.    30.00
```

Or you can use `stack`:

```
stack(summary(x))
#   values     ind
# 1   1.00    Min.
# 2  10.00 1st Qu.
# 3  15.00  Median
# 4  16.03    Mean
# 5  23.25 3rd Qu.
# 6  30.00    Max.
```